# Cancel OnLoad on Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` that overrides `OnLoad`. If an exception occurs I want to not instantiate the `UserControl`. How do I do this?

```
public partial class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this._presenter.OnViewReady();
            base.OnLoad(e);
            InitializeViewComponents();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, 
                "Error Loading Project", 
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            -- stop load here --
            //throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with `Visible = false;`?

Comment: That might work ... so the UserControl is not visible with that, but does the object still exist?

Comment: Yes it still exists. But you are asking about *I want to not display the UserControl*?

Comment: You are correct in what I stated. I would like to amend that by saying I don't want it to instantiate.

Comment: Instantiation is different from `OnLoad`.

Comment: I also suggest moving `base.OnLoad(e);` to the last line of `try` block if it's acceptable for your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiation happens by constructor and it's is different from `OnLoad` which happens when the control gets created. You cannot prevent instantiation in `OnLoad`, it's too late, however you can do in constructor by throwing an exception.

What you can do in `OnLoad` is prevent the control from getting visible by setting its `Visible` property to `false` and also if disposal of the control is a concern for you, you can remove it from parent's control collection and then dispose it:

```
Visible = false;
Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
Dispose();
```

Keep in mind, all the references to the control, then will point to a disposed object and `IsDisposed` of the control will be true and calling its members will result in an `ObjectDisposedException`. But the references to the control are not null.

Comment: Is it possible to Dispose an object from inside its `onload`?

Comment: @GuidoG Yes it is. And then `IsDisposed` property of the control is true and trying to call its methods and properties will result in `ObjectDisposedException`. For example assuming you have `myView1` control of type `MyView` (described in the question) then after the disposal, `myView1.IsDisposed` will be `true`.

Comment: I get an `InvalidOperationException` in my override of `Dispose` on the line `base.Dispose(disposing);` : 'Value Dispose() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle()'

Comment: But when you remove it from its parent, and dispose it, does the `Visible = false;` is then still needed ?

Comment: @GuidoG Not really, but I'd keep it, because it's the main thing which is asked in the question.

Comment: @AlLelopath No exception in a clean `UserControl` so, any exception will probably caused by your custom implementations in dispose.